# How to align radio buttons below the label in XHTML

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment, xhtml

I have a piece of code where i need to align radio buttons below the label name

for example:(Consider 1 and 2 as radio buttons)
**Animal**
  1 Cat
  2 Dog

I want to align radio buttons(1 and 2) to place just below the character "A"(Animal) instead of "N".

I wanted to do it only by inline CSS and I have tried many inline CSS with padding, margin etc. but nothing works for me. Need help!

Edit- Below is code for reference.

```
<l:field label="Animal">
  <z:selectOneRadio id = "A1" value = "#{newEntity.Animal}" layout="pageDirection" 
   showBorder="false">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cat">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dog">
  <z:selectOneRadio>
<l:field/>
```

*Note*- l,z,f are all third party defined tags.

Comment: share the code pls, so i can work off of what you have done

Comment: @WebDevDude sure. edited the question with code now.

Comment: is document css ok? not rly used to inline

Comment: btw ur code literally doesn't work in vscode

Comment: have to done it by inline only :( but if not then document css is also welcomed

Comment: yes it is bit messy but you can try it with simple radio buttons and a simple label

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not a JAVA developer, but your question is related to XHTML, I think I'm close to the solution. I'm almost sure you only have to set a fixed padding to the parent:

```
<z:selectOneRadio id = "A1" value = "#{newEntity.Animal}" layout="pageDirection" showBorder="false">
```

In your case this should do the job: `padding-left: 0px;`

It would be very helpful (I'm also sure you get more response on your topic when you do) if you show the generated HTML that you get after compiling the current code to us.

Good luck!